# How pass an argument as method of a module

Tags: python, argument-passing

Hi I want call `f('append','more','arguments',a=1,b=2)`

but append is a method(function) of `pyquery` module

so `arg[0]` is my method

I want make

```
    e.arg[0]('<div id="cool"></div>') run like e.append('<div id="cool"></div>')
```

-- so I want pass "append" as argument

```
    import pyquery
    d = pq('<div id="guido"></div>')
    d.append('<div id="cool"></div>')
    str(d)

    def f (*arg,**kargs):
        e = pq('<div id="guido"></div>')
        e.arg[0]('<div id="cool"></div>') # <== HERE
        return str(e)

    f('append','more','arguments',a=1,b=2)
```

so f('append','more','arguments',a=1,b=2) must return

```
    '<div id="guido"><div id="cool"/></div>'
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Can you rephrase and add more context?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question to slow clearly: (1) What pyquery does, (2) how you're trying to use it, and (3) why you're trying to use it that way?

Comment: There is nothing about pyquery. It is about pass argument and use this argument as a method of a module. So d.append('<div id="cool"></div>') works fine ok, but now I want pass 'append' to a function f() like f('append') ok, My function f() instance a module like e = pq('<div id="guido"></div>') and now I want use arg[0] {could be (append, after, before, appendTo, clone..)} in e.arg[0]('...') like e.append('...'), so I want e.arg[0]('..') run like e.append('...')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend against passing method names around in strings if you can avoid it (pass a reference to the method itself instead), but if you can't, what you want is `getattr()`, a function that gets an attribute of an object by a name contained in a string. This will let you get a reference to the desired method, and then you can call it as usual.

```
def f (*arg, **kargs):
    e = pq('<div id="guido"></div>')
    getattr(e, arg[0])('<div id="cool"></div>')
    return str(e)
```

Comment: yes, thanks. works fine. Sorry I cant vote, every question I make I loose points. :(

Answer (score 1):

pass d.append as the first argument. Functions are first class objects!